# Elasticsearch suggestion only where date is bigger than current

Tags: php, elasticsearch, autocomplete

Im working on portal with tennis tournaments and im using elasticserach as fulltext search engine.

I've created also autocomplete function with elasticsearch title suggester. But requirement for fulltext search is to search only future tournaments, so I need some solution for suggester, how to suggest only tournaments with starting date >= current datetime.

Is possible to make suggester, which returns results only with date bigger than today and for specific country ?

My actually config for autocomplete :

```
/**
 * Main search field autocomplete.
 *
 * @param $q
 * @return array
 */
public function autocomplete($q)
{
    $date = new DateTime();

    $results = $this->getClient()->suggest([
        'index' => 'tournaments',
        'body' => [
            'title_suggest' => [
                'text' => $q,
                'completion' => [
                    'field' => 'title_suggest',
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $resultData = [];

    foreach($results['title_suggest'][0]['options'] as $hit)
    {
        $resultData[] = $hit['text'];
    }

      return $resultData;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use completion suggest? If you're open to using the ngram method instead, you can still use arbitrary queries, so adding a date range filter to your query would not be difficult.

Comment: Agree on NGram queries.  The Suggesters don't have the same level of flexibility that the Query DSL does.  (Though it might be possible to add date-bounding to the Context Suggester since it already supports geo-distance bounding.)